# Qt TableView column and cell colors

Tags: qt, colors, tableview

I've got dialog with `QTableView` that is using `QSqlTableModel` and `QSortFilterProxyModel`, and they are reading from SQL Database. I want to change the color of my columns [3 , 4 , 5].
I am using the following code:

```
ui->tableView->model()->setData(
    ui->tableView->model()->index(1,2), 
    QVariant(QBrush(Qt::red)),
    Qt::BackgroundRole);
```

I am searching solution for 4 days already, and still nothing. Please tell me what to do. Whatever it is, i just need some new source code, or some other way, or just to edit my piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that neither the proxy model nor the `QSqlTableModel` will do anything with the background role. So you set it, but if you cared to check for the result returned by `setData`, you'd notice that it's false: what you're doing is a no-operation.

Just think about it: the SQL database in general has no way of storing an attribute like the background color together with other data in a given field. Similarly, the proxy model is there only to sort the data, and it doesn't give you any extra storage.

What you need to do is to insert a custom proxy between the table model and the sort/filter proxy. That proxy needs to store such extended attributes for you. Then it'll work.